How do I fix the "Modifier is disabled, skipping apply" error?
I am trying to add a Boolean union transformation for two objects (text and a former square) so I can combine them, if that's the correct word.
I am not in Edit Mode.


Please add an image of your Blender screen showing the outliner and modifier panel which you can do via Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu, editing your question and adding the image to it. - At the moment we have no idea what your settings are or exactly what you're trying to do.

If the modifier's icon is red then it's disabled and you cannot apply it. Check the modifier's setting there might be something missing or set to 0. Examples: Object is missing for the Boolean modifier or Levels Viewport is 0 for the Subdivision Surface modifier or the Simplify option with max level 0 is enabled which disables all Subdivision Surface modifiers.... please add a screenshot so that we don't have to keep guessing ;-)

@JohnEason@Blunder is this good?

Yes. that tells us what we need to know. You haven't actually selected an object to boolean on to the Cube! Click on the 'Object' line on the modifier and select the Text object on the menu that pops up. You should then be able to apply the modifier.

@JohnEason It worked, thanks a lot!

No problem. A nice simple one to solve if one has all the information! :^)
